IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain() vs D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain - When to use which for making a swap chain?
I'm following a bunch of tutorial series on how to set up Direct3D 11 for 3D rendering, I'm focusing on the swap chain part for now. The main tutorial series I am following is the one by PardCode on YouTube.
PardCode opts to use IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain() to create the swap chain from an IDXGIFactory, while other series on D3D11, such as the ones by ChiliTomatoNoodle and daivuk, use D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() to create both the device and the swap chain in one line. It looks to be the easiest option, so I'm not sure why PardCode would choose to use IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain() instead.
Aside from user friendliness and ease of use, what are the main benefits and drawbacks that come into play when one decides which approach to use to create a swap chain with DirectX 11?

If you look at the documentation for D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() you'll see that there are a few limitations of doing things that way, for example:

Note  This function has not been updated to support recent additional features of swap chain creation. For the most up-to-date swap chain creation methods, refer to the methods of IDXGIFactory2 (including CreateSwapChainForHwnd, CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow and CreateSwapChainForComposition).


Note  The D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain function does not exist for Windows Store apps. Instead, Windows Store apps use the D3D11CreateDevice function and then use the IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow method.

Depending on what you're doing, you may or may not care about those things. If the function works for you, then you can use it. If you want to use a feature that it doesn't support, then you'll need to use the newer APIs for that.

Thank you for the answer!
